# How to load start URLs with parameters?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Suppose my start URLs are paired with an ID each, e.g., `(http://www.foo.com, 53453)`. Is there a way to read the id in `parse()` given a response (assuming `response.url` is a start URL)? Is there a way to give response a custom 'payload'? I know I could do db lookups, but I wonder if it could be done in memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override [`start_requests()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) and `yield` `Request` instances passing `id` inside the [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) dictionary:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        items = get_url_and_ids_from_db()
        for url, id in items:
            yield Request(url, meta={'id': id})

    def parse(self, response):
        id = response.meta['id']
        ...
```

---

Alternatively, you can get the url->id mapping from the database in the `__init__()` and get the `id` by `response.url` in the `parse()` method:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.mapping = get_url_id_mapping_from_db()

        self.start_urls = mapping.keys()

    def parse(self, response):
        id = self.mapping[response.url]
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a long list of start URLs. Could the second method `yield` the URLs from db?

Comment: @Kate yeah, but I would not do db lookups in the `parse()` callback..would make web-scraping dramatically slower I suspect. Though, we should not optimize prematurely, you can try this approach.

Comment: @Kate what you can also do (I don't know what are you going to do with ids) is to move this part to the pipeline..

Comment: I quite like your first approach, and it works. I think I could `yield` the URLs there. Thanks!

Comment: My URLs and IDs are actually stored in a flat file. After scraping and parsing, the ID (along with everything interesting) are written to the DB. Should I do all the DB writing in `parse()` or in the pipeline?

Comment: @Kate pipeline is definitely the best place to write the scrapped data to the database.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that then. :)